# Keep row of buttons inline and with overflow x (in the mobile version)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

Using the bootstrap I developed a line with buttons.

My problem is that when I reduce the screen to a mobile version, the buttons are not in line, as shown in the image.

Is there a way to always put these buttons in line and if necessary with the overflow-x scroll available?

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/CmyCo3986D)

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 160px;">
    <a style="color: #51CC8B;" class="btnP" >Tots
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon1">34</span>
    </a>
    <a style="color: #4981C2;" class="btnR">Drops
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon">6</span>
    </a>
    <a style="color: #4981C2;" class="btnD">Drags
      <span class="nav-link btn-glyphicon">3</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the outer div to also use the `flex-nowrap` class:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center flex-nowrap" style="margin-top: 160px;">
```